# What does this notation means?

Tags: calculus, integration, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The question is calculate the coordinates of the center of gravity of the homogeneous domain (p(x,y)≡1) bounded by the curves

$x\in[0,1] , y\in[0,\sqrt{1-x^2}]$

I know it is a 1/4 circular area and we will calculate from there. However,

What does this notation $p(x,y)≡1$ tells us ?

Definite integral from 0 to 1 ? or what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p(x,y)$ is likely the function that describes the density at point $(x,y)$. In your case it's constant. That's what homogenous means in this context.

Yes, the integral from 0 to 1 of the region under $\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: Hence,will the coordinates be (4/(3*pi),4/(3*pi)) here in this question ?

Comment: And, sorry i am confused about something is 0 to 1 because it is homogeneous or because x∈[0,1] ? Which one is the case ?

Comment: The $x$ coordinate for the center of mass should be $\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ divided by the total mass. 0 to 1 is the interval of the width, so that's what we integrate. Those values are correct.